# Dropzone JS Listen To Success Event of Multiple Files Uploaded

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, dropzone.js

I'm using Dropzone JS and I have this code. It works fine :

```
    <script>
        $(function() {

            //-- Start DROPZONE --//
            var myDropzone = new Dropzone(".dropzone", { 
                url: "test2.php?token='.$product_token.'",
                maxFilesize: 2,
                maxFiles: 10,
                uploadMultiple: true
            });

            myDropzone.on("successmultiple", function(multiple) {
                $("#btn-addnew").removeClass("disabled");
            });
            //-- End DROPZONE --//

        })
    </script>
```

However, `$("#btn-addnew").removeClass("disabled");` executed when only one file get successfully uploaded. even there are 5 files still uploading. how to prevent `$("#btn-addnew").removeClass("disabled");` to be executed until ALL files successfully uploaded?

thank you so much for your attention.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue isn't with the dropzone success function. It's with your HTML `id` tag. ID's are only meant to be used in the DOM once, you are using it (sometimes) 5 times.

Change the `id` to a class, and then run your code.

```
class="btn-addnew disabled"
$('.btn-addnew').removeClass('disabled');
```

Comment: Hi bro, I tried to change into class as you said. instead of ID. but still act like the same. here's my button : `<button class="btn btn-danger btn-lg btn-addnew disabled" type="submit">Add New</button>` and here's the javascript : `$(".btn-addnew").removeClass("disabled");`

Comment: @RobertHanson Try it with the `complete` event instead of the `successmultiple` event, or `queuecomplete`